# How to create a sidebar with pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, sidebar

I need to create a desktop application with PyQt5. It will show different pages by clicking the buttons on the sidebar. So how to build a simple APP with sidebar?

Comment: Please post some code showing what you have tried so far. Your question, as it stands right now, is too broad. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example to create a sidebar for your application. Read more info in my [blog](https://www.luochang.ink/posts/pyqt5_layout_sidebar/).

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # set the title of main window
        self.setWindowTitle('Sidebar layout - www.luochang.ink')

        # set the size of window
        self.Width = 800
        self.height = int(0.618 * self.Width)
        self.resize(self.Width, self.height)

        # add all widgets
        self.btn_1 = QPushButton('1', self)
        self.btn_2 = QPushButton('2', self)
        self.btn_3 = QPushButton('3', self)
        self.btn_4 = QPushButton('4', self)

        self.btn_1.clicked.connect(self.button1)
        self.btn_2.clicked.connect(self.button2)
        self.btn_3.clicked.connect(self.button3)
        self.btn_4.clicked.connect(self.button4)

        # add tabs
        self.tab1 = self.ui1()
        self.tab2 = self.ui2()
        self.tab3 = self.ui3()
        self.tab4 = self.ui4()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        left_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        left_layout.addWidget(self.btn_1)
        left_layout.addWidget(self.btn_2)
        left_layout.addWidget(self.btn_3)
        left_layout.addWidget(self.btn_4)
        left_layout.addStretch(5)
        left_layout.setSpacing(20)
        left_widget = QWidget()
        left_widget.setLayout(left_layout)

        self.right_widget = QTabWidget()
        self.right_widget.tabBar().setObjectName("mainTab")

        self.right_widget.addTab(self.tab1, '')
        self.right_widget.addTab(self.tab2, '')
        self.right_widget.addTab(self.tab3, '')
        self.right_widget.addTab(self.tab4, '')

        self.right_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.right_widget.setStyleSheet('''QTabBar::tab{width: 0; \
            height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;}''')

        main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(left_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.right_widget)
        main_layout.setStretch(0, 40)
        main_layout.setStretch(1, 200)
        main_widget = QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)

    # ----------------- 
    # buttons

    def button1(self):
        self.right_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def button2(self):
        self.right_widget.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def button3(self):
        self.right_widget.setCurrentIndex(2)

    def button4(self):
        self.right_widget.setCurrentIndex(3)

    # ----------------- 
    # pages

    def ui1(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(QLabel('page 1'))
        main_layout.addStretch(5)
        main = QWidget()
        main.setLayout(main_layout)
        return main

    def ui2(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(QLabel('page 2'))
        main_layout.addStretch(5)
        main = QWidget()
        main.setLayout(main_layout)
        return main

    def ui3(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(QLabel('page 3'))
        main_layout.addStretch(5)
        main = QWidget()
        main.setLayout(main_layout)
        return main

    def ui4(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(QLabel('page 4'))
        main_layout.addStretch(5)
        main = QWidget()
        main.setLayout(main_layout)
        return main


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```